# How do I add to an object that I made in state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating an app that logs food submissions and I'm trying to update state for logFood, which is an object, and when I check to see if the state is updated, the state for logFood replaces the previous value. I'd like to add onto the object state and was wondering what options are available? Thank you!

````
state = {
        food: [],
        displayFoods: false,
        displayLogs: false,
        logFood: {},
        date: "001",
        meal: "breakfast",
        foodsSelected: [],
        reaction: "neutral",
    };


...


 submitFoodLog = () => {

        const date = this.state.date;
        const meal = this.state.meal;
        const foodsSelectedSubmission = this.state.foodsSelected;
        const reaction = this.state.reaction;
        const newLog = {
            dateKey: date,
            mealKey: meal,
            foodSelectedKey: foodsSelectedSubmission,
            reactionKey: reaction,
        };
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            logFood: { ...prevState.logFood, newLog },
        }));


    };```
````

Answer (score 3):

I think you got it right. Except for the fact that your spread operation looks a bit off, I think you need

```js
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  logFood: { ...prevState.logFood, ...newLog }
}));
```

spread even the `newLog` basically.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark as answer if it led to the solution.

Comment: Absolutely, did so. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use special `key` for each logged meal. for example:

```
let t = new Date.now().toString();
this.setState((prevState) => ({
            logFood: { ...prevState.logFood, [t]:newLog },
        }));
```

Comment: Awesome, I ended up using this. Thank you!

Comment: @Candace happy to help. If my answer helped you, I would be grateful if you vote it up and set it as an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Candace thank you, but you did not set my answer as an acceptable one yet.